# Mobify.js build encoding

Tags: javascript, encoding, character-encoding, cp1251, mobify-js

How can i do "mobify build" with result encoding `WINDOWS-1251`?
By default the character set of `mobify.js` is `UTF-8`, but the character set in the client site is `WINDOWS-1251`.

If I use iconv, enconv etc. then it helping me with setting encoding is `WINDOWS-1251` for `mobify.js`, but it breaks down the Russian characters. 
Thanx!

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: No your English is not bad at all!!

Comment: Thanks All! 
The problem was in the symbol `→`, it is not convertable from `UTF-8` to `WINDOWS-1251`. The solution is to replace `→` by `&rarr;` and app **enconv** with command `enconv -L ru -x WINDOWS-1251 ./bld/mobify.js`.
Hope this helps anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

The Mobify Client only supports building files encoded as UTF8.

Make sure that all your files (mobify.konf, any templates etc.) are saved in UTF8 encoding and you should be good to go!